# Asp.net 3.5, IIS7 and SQL Server 2008 Hosting recommendations

Tags: windows, hosting, web-hosting

I am looking for some suggestions for asp.net hosting on IIS7 with sql server 2008. I am assuming within this price range for windows shared hosting will be the go although vps would be great.

We are looking to spend $20 - $40 dollars a month with preference for the following:

- SQL Server 2008 storage space (minimum 1gb)
- Decent control panel / admin tools
- Knowledgable support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently hosting my .NET MVC site with [**ASPHostCentral**](http://www.asphostcentral.com) and so far, everything works smoothly. The following are my main reasons in choosing this host:

1. This host specialises in Windows and ASP.NET-based hosting only. IIS7, ASP.NET3.5, SQL 2008 are all Microsoft product and certainly, it will only work on Microsoft-based environment. I am looking for a host who truly focuses on Microsoft-based technology so that they can always keep up to date with the technology.
2. I am not looking for a "bombastic, unreasonable, unlimited" hosting features, such as unlimited disk space, unlimited bandwidth, unlimited everything whatsover. To me, all of these seems unreasoble as there is no such thing as unlimited stuffs. I am paying around $5 per month to ASPHostCentral just to get a decent, reasonble hosting feature with good uptime (and I receive this service very well)
3. I have seen many positive feedbacks about this host from several forum members and articles. Initially, I had problem getting up my Silverlight 3 application on their server, but they can rapidly and flexibly adjust their server to suit my requirements.
4. Excellent response time. I do not have to wait for days just to get a simple response.

As informed earlier, those are my main considerations in selecting this host, beside other "secondary" considerations, such as adequate disk space, domains, etc etc. I hope this can be useful to ya all....

Good luck!!!

Comment: Is the database storage included in the "Disk Space"?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to go to [**www.webhostingtalk.com**](http://www.webhostingtalk.com) and posting your requirements in the requests section as someone should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Www.discountasp.net

Are very good.

Answer (score 0):

you can have all this for less than 20$ here [www.kyhost.com](http://www.kyhost.com)
give it a try.